# Failed to fetch Java packages for oracle-java8-installer

Tags: java, linux, ubuntu, debian

We have a Vagrant Debian box with the option of installing Java and Solr 6.6. This installation setup was working until last month. Now we can not install Java.

Installation process:

**java-8-debian.list**

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main
```

in our provision.sh file:

```
sudo cp /vagrant/provisioning/java-8-debian.list  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/java-8-debian.list;

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886;

sudo apt-get -qq update
sudo apt-get install -qq -f -y python-software-properties software-properties-common debconf-utils unzip


sudo debconf-set-selections <<< "oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true"
```

**Now we have an error:**

```
~$ sudo apt-get install -f -y oracle-java8-installer
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package oracle-java8-installer
```

How to fix or locate the package?

**EDIT:**

we also try in terminal without -qq,  -f, -y, results are the same.

```
~$ sudo apt-get  update
Hit http://ftp.hosteurope.de jessie InRelease
Hit http://ftp.hosteurope.de jessie InRelease                                                                                                                                  
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty InRelease                                                                                                                                  
Hit https://packages.sury.org jessie InRelease                                                                                                                                 
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com jessie InRelease                                                                                                                                
Hit http://ftp.hosteurope.de jessie/main amd64 Packages                                  
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease                                  
Hit http://ftp.hosteurope.de jessie/main i386 Packages                                   
Hit http://ftp.hosteurope.de jessie/main ppc64el Packages                                                                                
Hit http://ftp.hosteurope.de jessie/main amd64 Packages                                                                                                                                      
Ign http://httpredir.debian.org jessie InRelease                                                                                                                                             
Hit http://ftp.hosteurope.de jessie/main i386 Packages                                                                                                 
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main Sources                                                                                 
Hit https://packages.sury.org jessie/main amd64 Packages                                                                    
Hit http://ftp.hosteurope.de jessie/main ppc64el Packages                                                                                   
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net trusty/main amd64 Packages                                                                   
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main Sources                       
Hit https://deb.nodesource.com jessie/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release.gpg 
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib Sources      
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages                   
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/contrib amd64 Packages  
Hit http://httpredir.debian.org jessie Release
Hit http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main Sources
Hit http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/contrib Sources
Hit http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages
Hit http://httpredir.debian.org jessie/contrib amd64 Packages
Reading package lists... Done
```

Comment: Problem can be in your sources-list. Also try removing `-qq` from apt-get update. There might be some warnings. From the man page: `you should never use -qq without a no-action modifier such as
           -d, --print-uris or -s as APT may decide to do something you did not expect.`

Also, this question might be better suited for different page: https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/aptitude

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj yes, we also try in terminal without -qq,  -f, -y, result its same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly you can't install oracje-java8 anymore because Oracle changed their licensing program.

You can use openJDK

```
apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
```

Here you can find additional infos regarding the issue: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java

Comment: no problem, please accepy my answer if it helped you

Answer (score 0):

Two ways
1.
Download java oracle from [here](https://www.oracle.com)

then go to your java directory

e.g: cd /root/java

then do

```
# makepkg -s
```

2.
download yay from [here](https://github.com/Jguer/yay) then go to yay directory

e.g: cd /root/Downloads/yay
in the yay directory in terminal do :

```
# makepkg -si
```

after install missing things do

```
yay install jre
```

Comment: sorry, but it won't work. oracle changed their licensing so you can't download it anymore